# Adding Semantic UI to Phoenix v1.4.3 with Webpack

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, semantic-ui

I am a newbie to Phoenix, Elixir, and Semantic.

I'm having an issue finding an example of how to add Semantic UI to Phoenix in the newest version 1.4.3 where it seems the file structure has changed a little and Webpack is now used instead of Brunch for asset generation. Tutorials on how to integrate Semantic with Phoenix date before the new version release and I'm unsure of where to put certain folders/files.

I've looked at these sites:

https://www.icicletech.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-phoenix-application-with-semantic-ui-and-webpack#semantic

[How to add Semantic-UI to Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36414396/how-to-add-semantic-ui-to-phoenix)

https://medium.com/@kimlindholm/adding-semantic-ui-sass-to-phoenix-with-webpack-36c7c96ef4e1

I've been testing out installing Semantic into my project and I get a `semantic` folder, `semantic.json` file, and my `package-lock.json` and `package.json` files get updated.

I moved the `semantic` folder which contains folders `src` and `tasks` into my `assets/static` folder and have updated my `endpoint.ex` file to contain the following:

```
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/",
    from: :app,
    gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt semantic)
```

Unsure of the next steps.

Comment: What do you expect? What does not work?

Comment: Since you have a tutorial for Phoenix 1.3, consider installing and using it first. After you get it working, follow the upgrade instructions for version 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

This question had been asked long ago. Might be the question raiser got the solution. But I am answering this to help others who are still looking for solution for this. I got a similar kind of requirement( Integrating Semantic UI with the Phoenix framework ). The below link helped me with step by step procedure. Please follow it.

```
 https://medium.com/@fivetwentysix/setting-up-semantic-ui-on-phoenix-framework-2cbd1d9c135
```